# Computing the Contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Compute the following integral for the following contours:

$$\displaystyle\int_\gamma \frac{\cos (z^2)+z}{z-\sqrt\pi}dz$$

a) $\gamma(t)=2e^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq2\pi $

b) $\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi it}$  for $0\leq t\leq 1$

c) $\gamma(t)=(1+i)+5e^{2\pi it}$  for $0\leq t\leq 1$

Here's what I did using :$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int^{2\pi}_{0}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$

$\displaystyle\int_\gamma \frac{\cos (z^2)+z}{z-\sqrt\pi}dz=\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{\cos (4e^{2it})+2e^{it}}{2e^{it}-\sqrt\pi}2ie^{it}dt=\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{2ie^{it}\cos (4e^{2it})}{2e^{it}-\sqrt\pi}dt+\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{4ie^{2it}}{2e^{it}-\sqrt\pi}dt$

How to continue after this?

Comment: Hint: Try Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: The antiderivative you need is probably not an elementary function.  Therefore, use of the residue method will be preferred to what you attempt.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look what the three parameterizations represent. Generally, $z_0+re^{2\pi i t},$ with $0\leq t\leq 1$ (equivalently $z_0+re^{i t}, \: 0\leq t\leq 2\pi $) is a circle of radius $r$ centered at $z_0$.

It is important to note that the integrand a simple pole at $z=\sqrt\pi$. Now we check if this pole lies in the given boundaries in order to apply Cauchy's integral theorem or Cauchy's integral formula.

For the first one, we have a circle of radius $2$, centered at the origin. Obviously $\sqrt\pi<2$, so the pole lies inside the boundary. We must apply Cauchy's integral theorem.

Use the same procedure to get the other solutions.